# Opentalk(Vonage) API set callertune for detect phone call ringing

Tags: android, kotlin, calling-convention, vonage

How to detect the time when a phone starts ringing for outgoing calls.I am developing an application in which i am trying to make a call programatically  and when call is connected to internet like whats app audio call app.i didnt found the solution how to detect call is ringing or busy to reciever side.
i connect my call using token key and session key through internet. my code is below for passing intent to call activity.

```
val intent = Intent(this@AstroDetailsActivity, CallActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(SESSION_ID_KEY, res!!.session_id)
                intent.putExtra(TOKEN_KEY, res.token)
                intent.putExtra("userId", MyApplication.sharedPreference?.userId.toString())
                intent.putExtra("astroId", astroId)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Hello, you have tagged this with the nexmo tag, are you using the Vonage Voice API (Originally Nexmo) to do this? Please include your code that is actually starting the call. Thank you!

Comment: @DevWithZachary i used Phone-Call-Detection-Kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/sample/phonecalldetection/MainActivity.kt this link for  voice calling

Answer (score 0):

The [example code](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/main/Phone-Call-Detection-Kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/sample/phonecalldetection/MainActivity.kt) doesn't make use of intent extras so I am unsure if you have made changes to this code to actually initialise.

But if you look in this activity you will see a `PhoneStateListener`. This object is attached to a call using:

```
private fun registerPhoneListener() {
    val telephonyManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
}
```

The `PhoneStateListener` then has a method `onCallStateChanged` which gets called when the current state of a phone call is changed. This can be overidden to carry out custom logic as below:

```
private val phoneStateListener: PhoneStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)

        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                publisher?.publishVideo = true
                publisher?.publishAudio = true
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> Log.d("onCallStateChanged", "CALL_STATE_RINGING")
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                Log.d("onCallStateChanged", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK")
                publisher?.publishVideo = false
                publisher?.publishAudio = false
            }
            else -> Log.d("onCallStateChanged", "Unknown Phone State !")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i use this code and phone listener but i coundn't hear any ringtone when i calling.so how to detect my call is send or not.

Comment: When the state is set to `CALL_STATE_RINGING` is when the call is ringing

Comment: but my call going in CALL_STATE_IDLE  how can i solve  this.